# Can not include xml schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I have following xml:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns="http://www.testuri.org" 
           targetNamespace="http://www.testuri.org" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="Price">
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:double" />
        <xs:element name="Currency" type="cs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And I want to use it in another xml file as include; I declare

```
<xs:include schemaLocation="Price.xsd"/>
```

but I see an error "The schema referenced from this location in your documents contains  errors".  As I look at the schema, above, I don't see any errors in it. Why this happens and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead element there should be type, and if I still need the element, I should use

```
<xs:element name="Price" type="Price"/>
```

in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a closing `</xs:simpleType>` that doesn't have a corresponding opening tag.

EDIT: After this was removed, I read further and found `<xs:element name="Currency" type="cs:string" />` which probably should read `<xs:element name="Currency" type="xs:string" />`.

Comment: You're right, there were another declaration up there, my mistake. Even without this, the error still here. Sorry for this, late hours...